# wp_nav_menu displaying all pages

Tags: functions, menus

As the title says, I'm using wp_nav_menu in header.php to load in the audience, secondary, and main menus and when I do, every menu contains every page - or at least many more pages than I selected for the menus.

I'm having the hardest time trying to make this work for some reason, so any help is appreciated. Here's the code to register the menus in functions.php:

```
// WordPress Menu Locations
function diviecommerce_setup() {
register_nav_menus(array(
    'primary' => esc_html__( 'Main Menu', 'diviecommerce' ),
    'audience' => esc_html__( 'Audience', 'diviecommerce' ),
    'secondary' => esc_html__( 'Secondary', 'diviecommerce' ),
    'footer ' => esc_html__( 'Footer', 'diviecommerce' ),
));
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'diviecommerce_setup');
```

And here's the code in the template:

```
<div class="top">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'audience', 'container_class' => 'audience' ) ); ?>
    <div class="header-right">
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'secondary', 'container_class' => 'account-cart' ) ); ?>
        <?php et_show_cart_total(); ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    <nav><?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'container_class' => 'main' ) ); ?></nav>
```

[image: Here's what this code spits out in browser]

Comment: In the Menu Settings at `wp-admin` → Appearance → Menus, did you check the option labeled "Automatically add new top-level pages to this menu"? Have you also confirmed your menus do not actually have those "every page" or duplicated pages? And are you sure you've assigned a menu to those theme locations like `audience`?

Comment: Expanding on Sally's last question, if a menu has not been assigned to a location, `wp_nav_menu()` calls to render that location default to falling back on a function which will use all available pages as menu content. See the `fallback_cb` argument of [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)

Answer (score 1):

Adding this here because it also took me forever to figure this out! Your code is correct, you're just missing one piece in /wp-admin !

Steps below:

**1. Register Menus in functions.php**

What you have is perfect, although I'm not sure you need "esc_html__" before setting the menu, but here's mine as an additional example)

```
// Setting Menus
function register_my_menus() {
register_nav_menus( array(
    'main_menu' => 'header',
) );
 }
 add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

**2. Call the menu in whatever file you want it to show**

Again, yours looks good, but here's just an additional example of how I used mine. Note, you might have to do some additional styling to get it to show how you want.

```
 <!--Calling Main Menu from funcitons.php-->
                <div>
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main_menu', 'container_class'=> 'menu_class' ) ); ?>
                </div>
```

**3. Assign the menus in /wp-admin (the missing piece)**

Head over to Appearance -> Menus -> Manage Locations. Your new menu should show up according to whatever you named it. Here you're going to assign it to the name of the menu you set under Edit Menus -> Create Menu.

Once you set it according to the location, it should show correctly!

Clarification image on the location below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkGxF.png

Hopefully this helps anyone else struggling here!